# First AdSense Ad displays randomly (async)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ads, adsense

I have some DFP (googletagId) ads and 4 adsense ads based on the async adsbygoogle.js script.
- Out of the 4 google adsense ads, the 1st adsense ad is visible randomly.

I have followed the following strategy for the google adsense:

```
<head>
....
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ad1">
<!-- Adsense #1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;min-width:320px;max-width:1200px;width:100%;height:110px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad2">
<!-- Adsense #2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;height:250px; width:300px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad3">
<!-- Adsense #3 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;height:250px; width:300px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad4">
<!-- Adsense #4 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;min-width:320px;max-width:1200px;width:100%;height:325px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

Adsense #1 is displayed randomly. i.e. sometimes it displays, sometimes not. As you can see in the image.
[image]

All other ads DFP and AdSense display properly, but the first AdSense Ad displays randomly.

Any help is appreciated!

> Note: I have posted this on [AdSense Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/JZS2C8TpL1U;context-place=forum/adsense) but it seems like Google Engineers don't want to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your adsense script to be something like this

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myAdsense ,3000);
function myAdsense() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
</script>
```

It might be not the best answer but it tricks the reload session so the adsense will keep appear.

**EDIT**

To display the remaining ads and keep your website perfomance up you can duplicate the function and stop the function when the ads is displayed. How? do something like this:

```
<head>
....
<script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ad1">
<!-- Adsense #1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;min-width:320px;max-width:1200px;width:100%;height:110px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myAdsense1 ,3000);
function myAdsense1() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
if (adsbygoogle == "[object Object]") clearInterval(myAdsense1);
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad2">
<!-- Adsense #2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;height:250px; width:300px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myAdsense2 ,3000);
function myAdsense2() {
    (adsbygoogle1 = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
if (adsbygoogle1 == "[object Object]") clearInterval(myAdsense2);
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad3">
<!-- Adsense #3 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;height:250px; width:300px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myAdsense3 ,3000);
function myAdsense3() {
    (adsbygoogle2 = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
if (adsbygoogle2 == "[object Object]") clearInterval(myAdsense3);
</script>
</div>
....
<div id="ad4">
<!-- Adsense #4 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;min-width:320px;max-width:1200px;width:100%;height:325px;"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); //so on
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Alert (adsbygoogle) and then try to read the value of that variable.For example, If google adsense appears, then `clearInterval(myAdsense)`; if not, then leave as it is. To keep up the performance,

Comment: I have more than one adsense. How is gonna work? If it was just one adsense it could work. 
- According to my description, ad#1 is problematic and the remaining ads ad#2, ad#3 and ad#4 display without any issues.
How can I that trick of yours target only the first ad?

Comment: Before I answer the next solution, would you please tell me the value of `adsbygoogle` first when the adsense is displayed? And what the value when the adsense is not displayed? You can know by following my second comment. I can't tell further because I don't have access to try the google adsense.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. when the ad is displayed, alert(adsbygoogle) returns `[object Object]` and when the ad is not displayed, alert does not display. even if I ad an extra string.

Comment: I edited the comment so you can review the code and try for yourself.

Comment: This is not ideal because I cannot verify when the ad is not displayed. Given that it simply can't be compared at all.